# "Bad Address" on calling execlp()

Tags: c, exec

This is simple program that would just exec 3 children. Each will create a lock, read a text file, and unlink the lock. If executed correctly the child will exit with it's process ID converted to 8 bits. The program will try for `n_try` times if it fails to create/unlink the lock, sleeping for a random time in between. I am fairly new with C and using exec() so I'm not sure what went wrong with my program. The first child executed correctly but anything after would return a `Bad address`. All I did was copying the exact code over. Some help would be greatly appreciated. The three arguments are the name of the text file, the number of tries to create/unlink a lock, and the sleep time in between the tries. Thank you!

Parent:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    pid_t childpid1, childpid2, childpid3; 
    char* fname = "lock"; 
    int fd, ret_val, status; 
    pid_t  w; 
    printf("I AM %d\n", (int)getpid());
    if ((childpid1 = fork()) == 0) { // If child 0 
        execlp("./proj3b", "./proj3b", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], "0", "lock"); 
    } 
    printf("I AM %d FORKED CHILD %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)childpid1); 
    while ((w = waitpid(childpid1, &status, 0)) && w != - 1) { 
        if (w != - 1) 
            printf ("Wait on PID: %d return status of: %04X\n", w, status); 
    } 
    unlink(fname); // Unlink the lock to make sure nothing is left.
    // End of child 1 
    printf("\nEND OF CHILD 0 \n\n"); 
    if ((childpid2 = fork()) == 0) { // If child 1 
        execlp("./proj3b", "./proj3b", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], "1", "lock");
        perror("Exec failure"); // Exec failed if this line is reached.
        exit(-1);
    } 
    printf("I AM %d FORKED CHILD %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)childpid2);
    while ((w = waitpid(childpid2, &status, 0)) && w != - 1) { 
        if (w != - 1) 
            printf ("Wait on PID: %d return status of: %04X\n", w, status); 
    } 

    unlink(fname); 
    printf("\nEND OF CHILD 1 \n\n");
}
```

Child:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *text; 
    char *fname;
    int n_try, sleeptime, fd, k, ret_val, count = 0, status;
    pid_t pid;
    text = argv[1]; 
    n_try = atoi(argv[2]); 
    sleeptime = atoi(argv[3]); 
    k = atoi(argv[4]);
    fname = argv[5];
    pid = getpid(); 
    ret_val = (int) (pid % 256); 
    srand((unsigned) pid); 
    while ((fd = creat(fname, 0)) == -1 && errno == EACCES) { 
        if (++count < n_try) 
            sleep(rand()%sleeptime); 
        else { 
            printf ("\n Unable to generate.\n"); 
            kill(pid,0); 
        } 
    } 
    if (!fork()) 
        execlp("/bin/cat", "cat", text, (char *) 0); // Reading text 
    while (wait(&status) >= 0); 
    while (unlink(fname)!=0) 
        if (++count < n_try) 
            sleep(sleeptime); 
        else { 
            printf ("\n Cannot release file\n"); 
            exit(-1); 
        } 
    exit(ret_val);  
}
```

Comment: You correctly terminated the argument list for `execlp` in the child but not in the parent.

Comment: How would I terminate the argument list for `execlp` in the parent?

Comment: The same way you did in the child!

Comment: OHHHHH!!! I get it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: OT: It's `int main` BTW!

Comment: OT^2: This `kill(pid,0);` is useless.

Comment: Well the prof just wanted the child to terminate with its child number, in this case it should've been k instead of 0. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly terminated the argument list for `execlp` in the child but not in the parent.